# Ruby Sequel ibmdb AdapterNotFound

Tags: ruby, docker, db2, sequel

I'm trying to connect to a db2-database with Sequel.
I'm on an OpenShift Platform using a CentOS-image with Ruby.
I installed ibm_db: `gem 'ibm_db', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.5'` and I'm trying to connect via Sequel as following:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'ibm_db'

require_relative 'database_logger'

def create_database_connection(logger)

  credentials = {
    adapter: "ibmdb",
    database: "myexampledb",
    host: "myexamplehost.com",
    port: "80",
    username: ENV['DB_USERNAME'],
    password: ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
    encoding: 'utf8'
  }

  if ENV['PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PORT'] =~ /^\d+$/
    credentials[:port] = ENV['PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PORT'].to_i
  end

  connection = Sequel.connect(credentials.merge(logger: DatabaseLogger.new(logger), encoding: 'utf8'))
  connection.extension(:connection_validator)
  connection.pool.connection_validation_timeout = -1
  connection
end
```

But I get the following message:

```
[1] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[1] * Version 3.11.3 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Love Song
[1] * Min threads: 2, max threads: 4
[1] * Environment: production
[1] * Process workers: 2
[1] * Preloading application
Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ibm_db-3.0.5/ibm_db.so
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/sequel-5.7.1/lib/sequel/adapters/ibmdb.rb:3:in `require'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/sequel-5.7.1/lib/sequel/adapters/ibmdb.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/sequel-5.7.1/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:88:in `require'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/sequel-5.7.1/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:88:in `load_adapter'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/sequel-5.7.1/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:17:in `adapter_class'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/sequel-5.7.1/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:45:in `connect'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/sequel-5.7.1/lib/sequel/core.rb:116:in `connect'
  /app/pact_broker/database_connection.rb:42:in `create_database_connection'
  config.ru:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/pact_broker-2.18.0/lib/pact_broker/app.rb:29:in `initialize'
  config.ru:9:in `new'
  config.ru:9:in `block in <main>'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:in `new'
  config.ru:in `<main>'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:318:in `load_rackup'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:243:in `app'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/runner.rb:138:in `load_and_bind'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/cluster.rb:397:in `run'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:183:in `run'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:77:in `run'
  /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.11.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/app-root/src/bin/puma:23:in `load'
  /opt/app-root/src/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
[1] ! Unable to load application: Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ibm_db-3.0.5/ibm_db.so
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/opt/app-root/src/bin/puma)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
ls -a /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ibm_db-3.0.5/
```

shows me the ibm_db.so.

ldd shows:

```
ldd /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ibm_db-3.0.5/ibm_db.so"
 ---> Running in a31043e66bbb
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcf9b44000)
    libruby.so.2.3 => /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/lib64/libruby.so.2.3 (0x00007f6af59f6000)
    libdb2.so.1 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6af57d3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6af55cf000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f6af5397000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6af5095000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6af4cd2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6af60a0000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f6af4ace000)
```

The libdb2.so.1 is present: `/opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/ibm_db-3.0.5/lib/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so.1`
but adding it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH as following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/ibm_db-3.0.5/lib/clidriver/lib/
```

does not help.
Maybe someone has an idea?

If I try to just copy `libdb2.so.1` to `/usr/lib64` libdb2.so.1 is found, but I get the following error: `! Unable to load application: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: UncaughtThrowError: uncaught throw :"Connection failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message \"0\" could not be retrieved. Reason code: \"3\". SQLCODE=-1042"`

Comment: Which IBM Db2 client have you installed (it delivers libdb2.so.1 among other things) ?

Comment: gem 'ibm_db', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.5'
I think this should provide all necessary drivers.

Comment: Verify libdb2.so.1 is present and ensure its directory is in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH by your chosen method.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how to verify the libdb2.so.1 is present?

Comment: Use the find command or equivalent

Comment: The libdb2.so.1 is present in /opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/ibm_db-3.0.5/lib/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so.1
Do I need to add it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH manually?

Comment: The aim is to eliminate this as a cause of your issue by ensuring that location is on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  See other posts for help on how to set (append to) that variable temporarily or permanently.

Comment: I appended it now as following: "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/app-root/src/.gem/ruby/gems/ibm_db-3.0.5/lib/clidriver/lib/", but the error is still the same...

Comment: Did you first close/stop ruby, make the change, then restart ruby?

Comment: Yeah, I'm working in a docker-container so I restart the whole machine when I change something.

Comment: ldd shows: libdb2.so.1 => not found, though I added the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If I copy the libdb2.so.1 to /usr/lib64 it works but I get SQLCODE -1042.

Comment: Seems your Docker config is not correct for both LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH and maybe others. You should not move Db2 library files around.  Docker is not my specialty although Db2-server runs fine in one of my docker containers as supplied by Db2-developer community edition. Maybe edit your question to add docker tag to get advice from docker folks.